# Why piping Get-Content of markdown files into one created a problem in npmjs.org?

Tags: powershell, npm

Ok, so I created a very, super simple script for publishing an NPM package:

```
Get-Content .\PublishNote.md > .\src\README.md
Get-Content .\README.md >> .\src\README.md
Set-Location .\src
npm publish
```

This basically creates a README.md file out of the contents of 2 other MD files.  When I used the script to publish, npmjs.org showed only some of the beginning of the compound file and with a space after each letter.  Furthermore, it showed two symbols at the very beginning.

Not being a stranger to Encoding, I am thinking the two symbols were a BOM and the spaces after each letter probably tells me the BOM was for Unicode 16-bit, either little or big endian.

I used Windows 11 and the Powershell shipped with Visual Studio Code:

```
Name             : Visual Studio Code Host
Version          : 2022.6.3
InstanceId       : ef44960d-264e-44e2-b28b-9a080de600f7
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : es-CR
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

Summarizing my question:  How can I make the Powershell script work in a way that it creates a file that is properly understood in npmjs.org?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try this: `Get-Content .\PublishNote.md | Set-Content .\src\README.md -Encoding UTF8` and `Get-Content .\README.md | Add-Content .\src\README.md -Encoding UTF8` or install [PowerShell 7.2.x](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases) which defaults to UTF8.

Comment: @zett42 I made your changes, tested and  compared using Beyond Compare.  Effectively, while the contents are marked identical, my original method produced a file with UTF16 LE BOM and your method forced UTF8.  I don't have updates to publish @ npmjs.org just yet, so I'll mark your comment as solution.  Appreciated.